# Sharepoint Online list and Common Data Service

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, sharepoint-list, common-data-service

When we create Power Apps in Microsoft teams by importing items from sharepoint online list to table. We then make canvas from the table. my question - if you Edit and item in Power Apps, will the change automatically get come on sharepoint on list

Answer (score 0):

yes this will happen but only when you have an edit form or functionality where in you use update a record in SharePoint.

[Take a look at this example from Microsoft especially edit form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint/scenarios-sharepoint-form-from-scratch#step-6--add-the-capability-to-edit-item)

Answer (score 0):

So if you are bringing in items from SharePoint into Dataverse for Teams then you will editing the data in Dataverse rather than SharePoint.
So to answer your question, no you won't see the changes in SharePoint.

Comment: Is there a way to update sharepoint list from dataversa by calling functions